# How can I make an object's function or property be a pointer to another object's function?

Tags: javascript, pointers, object

I have object testObj1 containing a number and a function which will increment and print that number.

```
testObj1 = 
{
    testNum: 0,

    testFunc1: function()
    {
        this.testNum++;
        console.log(this.testNum);
    }
}
```

And I also have object testObj2 with an empty function and another function whose parameter is assigned to the empty function.

```
testObj2 = 
{
    testFunc2: function() {},

    assignFunc: function(newFunc)
    {
        this.testFunc2 = newFunc;
    }
}
```

Now I try to assign testFunc1 to testFunc2 and run testFunc2.

```
testObj2.assignFunc(testObj1.testFunc1);

testObj2.testFunc2(); // Should output 1 but gives a NaN.
```

It seems that testFunc2 is just a copy of testFunc1 and tries to access testNum inside testObj2 where testNum doesn't exist. How can I make testFunc2 just be a pointer to testFunc1 so when I call testFunc2, it will call testFunc1 inside testObj1 which contains testNum?

Answer (score 0):

The 'this' in this case refers to the calling site (in this case because there are other alternatives). Your calling site is testObj2, which means the 'this' will refer to it. If you want, you can always bind the first object like this:

> testObj2.assignFunc(testObj1.testFunc1.bind(testObj1);

You might want to augment your assignFunc to take two values, the function and the 'this' context and use it like this:

```js
testObj2 = 
{
    testFunc2: function() {},

    assignFunc: function(newFunc, altThis)
    {
        altThis = altThis || this;
        this.testFunc2 = newFunc.bind(altThis);
    }
}
```

By the way, you can assign directly to the object without the need of an assignment function.